# Basic Group Policy Editor Stuff

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

My wife's/kids' computer just kicked the bucket... It was loaded with more malware, browser toolbars, and questionable software than you could shake a stick at!

So now, they will have to use MY computer, and I'm not going down without a fight! I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate, so I'm interested in using the Group Policy Editor to lock things down a bit...

I've done some reading today, and it seems I can use Group Policy Editor to accomplish what I'm after. However, I've never dabbled in Windows Administration and I need a bit of guidance. My first act as administrator, was to create the rest of the family a **Standard User** account.

Particulary, I'm very confused about how to use this whole Group Policy Editor. My account on the computer is an Administrator, but if I make changes under **Computer Configuration** or **User Configuration**, does that affect my administrator account as well?

Comment: Group policy is applied when logging onto a Windows Domain (ie. with a server acting as a domain controller).  You won't be able to use GPO's without that.  You can however use the "Local Security Policy" console to do some similar things.

Comment: @Coding Goriila: MLGPO has been available since Windows Vista. I've used it on a few occasions to lock down Windows 7 for non-Administrators.

Comment: @joeqwerty I see, I've never used MLGPO myself, but I started entering that comment before you responded, then walked away and came back.  I didn't see your answer until later. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create and configure a local Group Policy (Multiple Local Group Policy objects -  MLGPO) for non-Administrators in Windows 7. Here's a guide to doing so:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766291(WS.10).aspx